# Android MediaPlayer behavior (event order guarantees)

Tags: java, android, media-player

Assume two threads: my thread, and the MediaPlayer thread (which sends
messages to me through a looper). My game thread reacts to user input:
if the user pauses gameplay, I call MediaPlayer.pause() as well.

Consider the following order of events:

1. A MediaPlayer audio stream reaches its end, so it enqueues an
   OnCompletion message to me
2. My thread: MediaPlayer.pause() called due to user action
3. I receive the OnCompletion call (too late, pause() was already
   called above)

The problem with this is that MediaPlayer.pause() is only allowed in
PAUSED and STARTED state, but due to Step 1, the MediaPlayer will
already be in PlaybackCompleted state when pause() is called. I see
two solutions:

1. Catching exception
2. asking MediaPlayer.isPlaying() before calling pause()

But the second solution has a problem in the following scenario:

1. Game started, MediaPlayer.start() called, but mediaplayer state is
   *not yet* STARTED
2. User leaves gameplay, calling the code: if(isPlaying()) pause();
3. MediaPlayer enters STARTED state (now isPlaying would return true,
   but too late)

The problem here is that isPlaying() will still return false (as the
docs say too), so the MediaPlayer will still start due to step 3.

Is there a solution which is correct and avoids exceptions in both cases? (Or are there any mistakes in my above train of thought?)

---

**Update**

Reacting to Geobits' answer (I do it here because I'll quote from Android doc):

Yes, I'm also doing local playback, tested it a lot just like you, and everything looked fine. But the documentation is a bit self-contradicting. The first part (this is OK):

> Calling start() to resume playback for a paused MediaPlayer object,
>   and the resumed playback position is the same as where it was paused.
>   When **the call to start() returns, the paused MediaPlayer object goes
>   back to the Started state**.

And another quote from the same page:

> Playback can be paused and stopped, and the current playback position
>   can be adjusted. Playback can be paused via pause(). When the call to
>   pause() returns, the MediaPlayer object enters the Paused state. Note
>   that the transition from the Started state to the Paused state **and
>   vice versa** happens asynchronously in the player engine. **It may take
>   some time before the state is updated in calls to isPlaying()**, and it
>   can be a number of seconds in the case of streamed content.

This latter one says that also when *starting* a paused player, the state change may take time ("vice versa"). So far so good, because it only applies to the internal player engine, but then comes the crazy part: *"It may take some time before the state is updated in calls to isPlaying()"*. This implies that isPlaying() **isn't returning the OBSERVABLE state**, instead it depends on the internal state. This is confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done a few apps with MediaPlayer, and used `if(isPlaying()) pause();` each time with no bad effects. That's with local media, though. If you're streaming the latency might actually cause the second type of problem.

Try it out and see if you can break it. If you can't, it's nothing to worry about. If you can, you can always work around it. Setting a boolean when you call `start()`, queuing the pause, I'm sure there's other methods I'm not thinking of.

But try it out first. It behaves well for me, and I've playtested the crap out of mine.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. A few days ago, just to be sure, I implemented a workaround (actually a foolproof) solution, yes. Nonetheless, my results are the same as yours, but the documentation is really confusing at a certain part: please see my original question post for quotes (I updated it at the end).

Comment: Yea, the documentation for that class is horribly confusing, no matter how many pretty diagrams and charts they add. I nearly tore my damn hair out trying to get the wakelock to work correctly in all situations.

Comment: Another contradicting stuff is whether you can call pause() in PlaybackCompleted state or not. According to the documentation, you cannot (it transfers to Error state), but in practice, you can. And considering you cannot really check synchronously whether playback is complete (you only have the onCompletion callback), you cannot know (without tricks) if your pause() call is safe or not. I sent a question to them, but no answer so far:
http://groups.google.com/group/android-platform/browse_thread/thread/5ed3ed460880c0fc#

Comment: MediaPlayer has a lot of problems. It can't even give a proper `getCurrentPosition()` half the time. It made doing a rhythm game really difficult. There have been numerous bug reports all over the class for years now, hopefully your question gets more attention than the rest.

Comment: getCurrentPosition() does not work for VBR (and some CBR) OGG files, but it works OK for other formats. Offtopic, but: for OGG files, it might even be an intentional negligence, because getCurrentPosition() seems to return discrete (~like quantified) values when used periodically, and these values have the approximately the same distance from each other (e.g. if you use an own counter that measures in every 100ms, then you get 0,100,200,300,400 while getCurrentPosition returns values like 302,302,302,542. As if generated some sort of own seek index for OGG, a really rough one.

Comment: And I think the reason seek() does not work for OGG files is that it relies on getDuration(). So it's able to seek correctly, but if you want to seek over the flawed duration value, the check will fail and thus seek will fail too. And getDuration() is totally flawed for OGG files (unlike getCurrentPosition() which seems to have some regularity). Crazy... And they haven't been dealing with the question for more than a year: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15441

Comment: For all MP3s I've tried(hundreds, both CBR and VBR), it works fine until I call pause() and then start(). Apparently it keeps counting through the pause, and so after a restart you get the total time elapsed since calling start() the first time. I had to keep a timer of how long it had been paused and subtract it from getCurrentPosition() to keep things synced up. The strange thing is I see no mention of it on boards, and I know it can't just be me.

Comment: As for getDuration(), I try to use it as little as possible. My music pulls from the Media library, and the metadata there seems to be more accurate. Haven't played with OGG much to notice on those.

Comment: I also have some own auxiliary mechanisms. Even though pause(), start() and getCurrentPosition() seems to work for me currently. What I **really hope** is that something that WORKS now (regarding MediaPlayer seek and getCurrentPosition) will not get broken in the future. I know they take care of that, but after seeing all these issues with MediaPlayer, I'm sceptic.

Comment: @Geobits - I've seen the behaviour where getCurrentPosition changes even while in paused state.  Keeps incrementing, and when I Call start() it returns to the location when I originally paused.